# Patent scraper always gets IP blocked even with time.sleep

Tags: python, web-scraping, web-crawler

I have written this code that is supposed to scrape patent search results from the website of the USPTO when given a list of terms to search. I am using a randomized time.sleep in order to avoid getting banned; however, I am still getting my IP blocked temporarily, which results in a lack of results. What else can I do in order not to get stopped?

```
import pypatent
from selenium import webdriver
import pandas as pd
import re
import time
import numpy as np


dataish = pd.read_csv("trialeer.csv")
symbols_to_keep = "1234567890qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnmQWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM:;!-,?.@ \n\""
remove_unknown_chars = lambda x: ''.join(char for char in x if char in symbols_to_keep)
def clean_tweets(twoot):
    # Convert to lowercase and remove spaces from beginning
    twoot = str(twoot).lstrip()
    # Remove Twitter-related data
    #twoot = remove_user_tags(twoot)
    #twoot = remove_urls(twoot)
    #twoot = remove_hash_tags(twoot)
    # Remove unwanted characters
    twoot = remove_unknown_chars(twoot)
    # Remove spaces from end and condense multiple spaces into one
    twoot = twoot.rstrip()
    twoot = re.sub(' +', ' ', twoot)
    return twoot

dataish["NER Model"] = dataish["NER Model"].apply(clean_tweets)
list1 = dataish["NER Model"].to_list()
liste2= list(filter(lambda a: a != '', list1))
newlist = []

for element in liste2:
   newlist += element.split(',')
newlist = [x.strip() for x in newlist]


def uspatent(x):
    driver = webdriver.Chrome('./chromedriver')
    conn = pypatent.WebConnection(use_selenium=True, selenium_driver = driver)
    x = pypatent.Search(x, results_limit=5, get_patent_details=True, web_connection=conn).as_dataframe()
    return x

for item in newlist:
    try:
        print(uspatent(item))
        delays = [7, 4, 6, 2, 10, 19]
        delay = np.random.choice(delays)
        time.sleep(delay)
    except:
        pass
```

Comment: wait longer? I'd bet the firewall is looking at connections per hour(ish). No normal human is going to be making an average of over 400 requests per hour.

Answer (score 1):

You are making too many requests per day. According to http://patft.uspto.gov/

(paraphrased)

> IP addresses that generate over 10000 database hits in a day (roughly
> 1000 patent views) will be blocked.

I'm sure searches generate more DB hits than viewing individual patents, and run out very quickly. You are supposed to look [here](https://www.uspto.gov/learning-and-resources/bulk-data-products) for bulk data needs. Given that you may be able to modify `pypatent` to use this alternate data source, or you will need another method to find the data you need.